# UIView AnimateKeyFrames All At Once

Tags: objective-c, animation, uiview, nslog, duration

Why are all of my NSLogs being run at once?

My understanding is that each one should be separated by one second. Is that incorrect?

```
[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:5.0 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:0.0 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"1");
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:1 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"2");
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:2 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"3");
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:3 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"4");
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:4 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"5");
        }];
        [UIView addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:5 relativeDuration:1 animations:^{
            NSLog(@"6");
        }];
    } completion:nil];
```

Here is my Log:

```
2015-03-28 14:10:52.409 AppName[636:80664] 1
2015-03-28 14:10:52.409 AppName[636:80664] 2
2015-03-28 14:10:52.409 AppName[636:80664] 3
2015-03-28 14:10:52.409 AppName[636:80664] 4
2015-03-28 14:10:52.410 AppName[636:80664] 5
2015-03-28 14:10:52.410 AppName[636:80664] 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relativeStartTime is wrong, this value should be from 0.0 to 1.0, which is the percentage of the whole duration.

Please see apple's comments for this function:

**start time and duration are values between 0.0 and 1.0 specifying time and duration relative to the overall time of the keyframe animation**

or

**The time at which to start the specified animations. This value must be in the range 0 to 1, where 0 represents the start of the overall animation and 1 represents the end of the overall animation. For example, for an animation that is two seconds in duration, specifying a start time of 0.5 causes the animations to begin executing one second after the start of the overall animation.**

Ref: [see more](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations:)